# Mutate statement not working to enable graph

Tags: r, dplyr, timeserieschart, tsibble

Working through a tidyverse time series example on the sunspot data, getting the following error message when I try to graph in 10 year increments, seems to not recognize the new date variable created in step 1, wondering if this is a format issue.
Error: Problem with `mutate()` column `decade`.
i `decade = f(date)`.
x subscript out of bounds

Appreciate any help

```
# libraries
library(datasets)
library(tidyverse)
library(tsibble)
library(ggplot)

# Tidy the data
tidy_ts <- sunspots %>%  
  as_tsibble() %>%        # Convert to timeseries tibble
  mutate(                 # Create new variables
    year = year(index),   # Create a year column
    month = month(index)  # Create a month column
  ) %>%
    select(                 # Select, reorder, rename vars
        date = index,         # Rename "index" to "date"
        year,                 # Use "year" as second variable
        month,                # Use "month" as third variable
        spots = value         # Rename "value" as "spots"
    ) %>%
    print()                 # Show data
view(tidy_ts)

# Graph the tidy data by decade
tidy_ts %>%
  index_by(                            # By decade
    decade = ~ floor_date(tidy_ts$date, years(10))
  ) %>%
  summarise(mean_s = mean(spots)) %>%  # Mean for decade
  ggplot(aes(decade, mean_s)) +        # Plot means
  geom_point() +                       # Scatterplot
  geom_smooth() +                      # Smoother
  ylab("Sunspots: Mean by Decade")     # Label
```

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing:

```
index_by(                            # By decade
    decade = ~ floor_date(tidy_ts$date, years(10))
)
```

with:

```
index_by(decade = floor(year/10)*10)
```